# How to send uint as an additional data with sendTransaction

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript

In my web interface i am sending an id of a product and some amount of ETH to a smart contract.

```
instance.sendTransaction(productId, {from: account, value: amountToSend });
```

And in the smart contract i am trying to handle it lake this:

```
 address[16] public balances;

  function (uint productId) external payable {
    require(productId >= 0 && productId <= 15);

    data[productId] = msg.sender;
  }
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Fallback function cannot take parameters.
```

So how can I send and read that `productId` inside of my contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed the fallback function cannot take parameters. a fallback function should be defined as :

```
 function() payable {...}
```

however in your case you can define another payable function which should be called instead.

```
contract.your_method.sendTransaction(id, {from: account, value: amountToSend })
```

.

```
 your_method(uint productId) external payable {
    require(productId >= 0 && productId <= 15);

    data[productId] = msg.sender;
  }
```